# How to keep the first 200 words from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (called news). In this dataframe there are articles and in column 'content' there is every article's full text. In need to keep only the first  200 words from every article.

[image]

Comment: @KarlWilhelm: I'll remove your dupe comment from the other post then, seeing as you found the right browser tab :-)

Comment: Try `news['content'].str.split().str[:200].str.join(' ')`